# Personalization default condition is not triggering

Tags: personalization

I want to do the personalization for a particular component when the anonymous user will revisit the site whereas the rule which I have set is "where the visit no. is greater than 1".I haven't cleared any cookie of the browser. Xdb.Enabled and Xdb.Tracking.Enabled settings in the Sitecore.Xdb.config file both are changed to true. IndexAnonymousContactData>true also changed.The number of visits are increasing but the personalization condition is not triggering for the defaulf one also.Please help me in rectifying that.Iam using 9.0 update 1 instance

[image: de]

Comment: So you don't see the component at all or what's happening? Are you sure you published all the datasources and the page itself? Are you testing it in a normal mode or preview/editing mode?

Comment: I have published it and Iam testing it in CD(Content Delivery)

Comment: So what's happening? What is the output?

Comment: The personalization itself is not working.Whatever the datasource we have assigned to that component,its showing that thing only in CD.

Comment: What do you mean by "personalization itself is not working"? Could you explain what do you expect and what do you have in real? Anonymous user who visit website many times from one browser should see "HeaderGoaContent" datasource but he see "HeaderContent", right ?

Comment: Yes,but this issue is resolved.Thankyou for your help

Comment: How did you solve this issue?